# Android Internal Storage, how to properly parse a JSON text file

Tags: android, json

I'm creating an Android app which creates a text file with JSON objects and writes it to internal storage.  I have the following code to do that:

```
JSONObject myJSON = new JSONObject();
//Set the JSON object with website, length and Id (time-stamp)
try {
    myJSON.put("Length", trim)
    .put("Website", data)
    .put("Id", tx);
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

//Convert JSON object to a string and add a comma
String myJSONString = myJSON.toString();
myJSONString += ", ";

try {
     FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
     fos.write(myJSONString.getBytes());
     fos.close();
     //Log.d(TAG, "Written to file");

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "cought");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now I get a text file which looks like so:

```
{"Id":"20101211T155146","Length":10}, {"Id":"20101211T155155","Length":10},
{"Id":"20101211T155203","Length":10}, {"Id":"20101211T155252","Length":10},
```

I'd like to now collect that data in the JSON file. The app needs to write, store and retrieve the JSON. The problem is when I go to parse the JSON objects from the file using:

```
String x = "";
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pwh);
byte [] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
while (is.read(buffer) != -1);
String jsontext = new String(buffer);
JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(jsontext);

x = "JSON parsed.\nThere are [" + entries.length() + "]\n\n";

int i;
for (i=0;i<entries.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject post = entries.getJSONObject(i);
    x += "------------\n";
    x += "Id:" + post.getString("Id") + "\n";
    x += "Length:" + post.getString("Length") + "\n\n";
}
```

It throws an error.  I got the parsing code from a great tutorial at: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/x-andbene1/?ca=drs-#author1
In that example, the code is expecting brackets around the whole file and no comma after the last object.  So I would need:

```
[{"Id":"20101211T155146","Length":10}, {"Id":"20101211T155155","Length":10},
{"Id":"20101211T155203","Length":10}, {"Id":"20101211T155252","Length":10}]
```

But I write those JSON lines one at time in my code; How can I manipulate the JSON text file to get it in the expected format?

**UPDATE:**

The problem is still that if the user writes the JSON array to the file and then comes back and changes it again, you get **two JSON arrays** in that file.  Like so:

```
[
     {
          "phonenumber": "15555215554",
          "time": "20110113T173835",
          "username": "edit username",
          "email": " edit email",
          "password": "edit password"
     }
][
     {
          "phonenumber": "15555215554",
          "time": "20110113T173900",
          "username": "edit username",
          "email": " edit email",
          "password": "edit password"
     },
     {
          "phonenumber": "15555215554",
          "time": "20110113T173900",
          "username": "edit username",
          "email": " edit email",
          "password": "edit password"
     }
]
```

How can I read the first array, add the second and then re-write the file with both arrays merged into one?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `JSONArray` to create an array of `JSON objects`. Once you do a toString(), you will have the expected brackets. You do not need to manually add the commas either.

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html for more info

Answer (score 0):

1. to make this a valid JSON array, you need to encapsulate the JSON-Objects (`{...}`) in braces (`[]`). Thus, you could put `[` into the file on creation and

   - either have a single point where the array is finished and you just write a closing brace `]` instead of the next comma (`,`), or
   - you do not have such a single point. Whenever you write the next object, you might be able to go back one byte in the stream via [f.ex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9559095/1587329)

     ```
     try {
         FileChannel ch = fos.getChannel();
         ch.position(ch.position -1);
         ch.write(", ".getBytes());
         ch.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(myJSONString.getBytes()));
         ch.write("]".getBytes());
     } finally {
         out.close();
     }
     ```
2. (concerning the "UPDATE"):
   Just read the whole array from the file, update it in memory (via [JSONArray.put()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#put%28java.lang.Object%29)), and overwrite the file.

   To overwrite, replace the `Context.MODE_APPEND` with 0, as written in [the API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

   It would be better if you created the array correctly. If you are given the arrays as in your update, you could search for the occurrence of `][`, split your file on that, create the JSON from both objects, and merge those (once again, via [JSONArray.put()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#put%28java.lang.Object%29)).