# How to parse htmltags in a json in android

Tags: android, html, json

I have a json file and one of its Jsonobject contain an html tag.My problem is that i can't parse that json object.  How can i do that?  Here is the sample for json file

```
{
"data": {
    "insert": [
        {
            "category": "Fashion",
            "blog_title": "Bold Floral Tunic Dress",
            "blog_descr": "Get the look of spring&rsquo;s bold florals with this flowy tunic dress.&nbsp; What we love about it is the bold colors and the hyper-realist print&hellip;reminiscent of the work of British designer Mary Katrantzou.&nbsp; Extra bonus?&nbsp; At this price, it&rsquo;s not just easy to wear - it&rsquo;s also easy on the wallet.$79.90&nbsp; at Zara",
            "source": "omiru",
            "rate": "7.9",
            "status": "Active",
            "blog_date": "25-04-2012 14:53",
            "last_view_date": "11-09-2012 22:19",
            "blog": "<p><img class=\"alignnone size-full wp-image-8558\" title=\"bold-floral-tunic-dress_042312\" src=\"http://www.omiru.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/bold-floral-tunic-dress_042312.jpg\" alt=\"bold-floral-tunic-dress_042312\" width=\"455\" height=\"583\" /><br /><span style=\"font-size: x-small;\"><br />Get the look of spring&rsquo;s bold florals with this flowy tunic dress.&nbsp; What we love about it is the bold colors and the hyper-realist print&hellip;reminiscent of the work of British designer Mary Katrantzou.&nbsp; Extra bonus?&nbsp; At this price, it&rsquo;s not just easy to wear - it&rsquo;s also easy on the wallet.<br /></span><br /><span style=\"font-size: large;\">$79.90</span><span style=\"font-size: x-small;\">&nbsp; at <a href=\"http://www.zara.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product/us/en/zara-us-S2012/199002/787510/PRINTED%2BTUNIC%2BWITH%2BCAP%2BSLEEVES\" target=\"_blank\"><span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">Zara</span></a>.</span></p>",
            "blogid": "218",
            "comments": "50"
        },
        {
            "category": "Fashion",
            "blog_title": "April 2012 Lookbook: Urban Playground",
            "blog_descr": "This look is part of Omiru&rsquo;s April 2012 Lookbook series, which builds upon our 16-Piece April 2012 Capsule Wardrobe.&nbsp; See more information about this look.We&rsquo;re dreaming of the carefree days of childhood - of playground games, of laughter and fun, of adventure in the ordinary.&nbsp; But even if your spring days are destined to be",
            "source": "omiru",
            "rate": "8.1",
            "status": "Active",
            "blog_date": "25-04-2012 14:53",
            "last_view_date": "11-09-2012 22:19",
            "blog": "<p><img title=\"Omiru\"s April 2012 Lookbook: Urban Playground\" src=\"http://embed.polyvoreimg.com/cgi/img-set/cid/47694438/id/-wzdDuNKQ5WoEt0claUYLA/size/e.jpg\" alt=\"Omiru\"s April 2012 Lookbook: Urban Playground\" width=\"400\" height=\"400\" border=\"0\" /><br /><span style=\"font-size: x-small;\"><em>This look is part of Omiru&rsquo;s April 2012 Lookbook series, which builds upon our <a href=\"http://www.omiru.com/index.php/2012/04/02/omirus-16-piece-april-2012-capsule-wardrobe/\">16-Piece April 2012 Capsule Wardrobe</a>.&nbsp; See <a href=\"http://www.polyvore.com/omirus_april_2012_lookbook_urban/set?.embedder=101223&amp;.svc=copypaste&amp;id=47694438\" target=\"_blank\">more information about this look</a>.</em>We&rsquo;re dreaming of the carefree days of childhood - of playground games, of laughter and fun, of adventure in the ordinary.&nbsp; But even if your spring days are destined to be spent in a metropolis, you need not lose the playfulness in your style. For the urban playground, keep the simple silhouettes - updating them with more sophisticated fabrics, patterns, and colors.&nbsp; Also keep your sense of serendipity and wonder - which will help you navigate the urban playground just as well as you ruled the neighborhood playground way back when.1. Start with a chic but comfortable foundation: an oversized cropped tee paired with a buttery pair of knee length leather shorts.&nbsp; The cropped tee works with the high rise on the short and calls attention to the leg-lengthening silhouette.<br />2. Enough black and white with this foundation - it&rsquo;s time to add color!&nbsp; Toss on a cardigan in a bright yellow to offset the black and white of the tee and shorts.&nbsp; Bonus points for toting around a handbag in a complementary bright color - notice how the turquoise bag adds an extra dimension to the yellow, black, and white of the look.<br />3. Finish off the look with accessories with an edge - a pair of studded gladiator sandals, a leather wrap bracelet with a skull motif, and a retro chic pair of sunglasses.&nbsp; <br /><strong><br />What do you wear to navigate the urban playground?</strong>&nbsp; Share your style in the comments!<br /></span></p>",
            "blogid": "219",
            "comments": "53"
        },
        {
            "category": "Food",
            "blog_title": "Lai Kee Dim Sum:  Novel bits and bites",
            "blog_descr": "Dim Sum $1.80 to $2 per basketThere are several hawker genres that should do well in Singapore and Dim Sum is one of them.&nbsp; The reason is very simple.&nbsp; Every customer will spend more than $3-4 per pax.&nbsp; If you survey the current hawker scene, you will see Bak Kut Teh stalls springing up all over the place.&nbsp; That is because",
            "source": "ieatishootipost",
            "rate": "8.1",
            "status": "Active",
            "blog_date": "25-04-2012 14:53",
            "last_view_date": "11-09-2012 22:19",
            "blog": "<p><a href=\"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ETJZGZWwUW8/T4ZVSwz5ymI/AAAAAAAAR8Y/YwZutmTZwkU/s1600/Siew+Mai.jpg\"><img src=\"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ETJZGZWwUW8/T4ZVSwz5ymI/AAAAAAAAR8Y/YwZutmTZwkU/s800/Siew+Mai.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"500\" height=\"332\" border=\"0\" /></a><br /> <span style=\"font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: x-small;\"><em>Dim Sum $1.80 to $2 per basket</em></span><br /> <br /> There are several hawker genres that should do well in Singapore and Dim Sum is one of them.&nbsp; The reason is very simple.&nbsp; Every customer will spend more than $3-4 per pax.&nbsp; If you survey the current hawker scene, you will see Bak Kut Teh stalls springing up all over the place.&nbsp; That is because people expect to pay $5-6 at least when they eat Bak Kut Teh.&nbsp; So that is going to ensure the survival of Bak Kut Teh as a Hawker dish.&nbsp; Things like Char Kway Teow which can only sell for $3 a plate is less attractive for any aspiring hawker to take on so unless something happens and a Char Kway Teow emerges that people are willing to pay $6 for, then it really is \"<a href=\"http://ieatishootipost.sg/2010/12/end-of-char-kway-teow-ieatishootipost.html\">The End of Char Kway Teow</a>\" as we know it.<br /> <br /> But today we talk about an emerging Hawker dish.&nbsp; I guess Dim Sum is not really what people will consider a traditional Hawker food, but with increasing affluence, stalls which were initially selling only Paus would invariably be attracted to increasing their revenue by offering other Dim Sum dishes.&nbsp; With Dim Sum at the restaurants now averaging around $4-$5++ a basket, I see a big opportunity for more hawkers to offer a cheaper alternative in a coffeeshop setting.<br /> <br /> The other good thing about Dim Sum is that the food can be standardized and prepared in a central kitchen beforehand and steamed fresh at the premises when you order.&nbsp; So that allows for opportunities to expand.&nbsp; At $2 a basket, the average spend for a customer would be at least $8-$10 which essentially triples what you would earn if you sell Char Kway Teow!<br /> <br /> With more hawker Dim Sum emerging and restaurant Dim Sum getting ridiculously expensive, I am hoping to see more stalls such as Lai Kee emerging so that we can all spend a lazy morning drinking eating Dim Sum and drinking Teh C without having to pay for peanuts and ++.&nbsp;&nbsp; So, if you know of any good hawker Dim Sum stalls, please do write in and let me know so that I can build a list good Dim Sum stalls to visit.<br /> <br /> <a href=\"http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-J6lTLrdcqqw/T4ZVRLQgi6I/AAAAAAAAR8I/WWPwy_s1W4c/s1600/Dim+Sum+Selection.jpg\"><img src=\"http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-J6lTLrdcqqw/T4ZVRLQgi6I/AAAAAAAAR8I/WWPwy_s1W4c/s800/Dim+Sum+Selection.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"500\" height=\"500\" border=\"0\" /></a><br /> <span style=\"font-size: x-small;\"><span style=\"font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;\"><em>Variety of Dim Sum</em></span></span><br /> <br /> The man who started Lai Kee, Ah Lai started off helping to make Dim Sum with&nbsp; relatives in Malaysia before coming out to Singapore to start his own stall.&nbsp; His first stall was at Clementi and has now expanded to four branches.&nbsp; He tells me that Dim Sum might be more lucrative but it is a lot of hard work.&nbsp; Now that he has four stalls, he has hired a few Dim Sum chefs to help hand make the Dim Sum every day at the stalls while he prepares the meat, prawn and fish pastes centrally.<br /> <br /> What I like about Lai Kee is their variety of unusual Dim Sum.&nbsp; The standard fare of Siew Mai and Har Kau are of course available and judging from the Siew Mai, the basic meat filling is very good and well marinated.&nbsp; Ah Lai pays special attention to this and uses only fresh Indonesian pork instead of frozen meat to ensure quality.&nbsp; But he has spent a lot of time thinking up new dishes as well and the wonderful thing about eating there is that you get to try something new instead of the same-o same-o.<br /> <br /> I was drawn immediately to the Century Egg dumplings because they reminded me of the marvelous breakfast I had at <a href=\"http://ieatishootipost.sg/2010/03/sim-sim-pier-7-breakfast-to-remember.html\">Sim Sim Pier</a> in Sandakan.&nbsp; Then there are other permutations and combinations of tasty morsels made from tofu, bean curd skin, meat, prawn and fish filling.&nbsp; I can\"t say that it tastes as exquisite as the Dim Sum you get at the restaurants, but the affordability, variety and pretty decent food quality certainly makes it a compelling candidate for a quick Dim Sum fix.<strong><span style=\"color: red;\"> 4/5</span></strong><br /> <br /> <br /> <a href=\"http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-_t2-e91Hjmc/T4ZVSD9tupI/AAAAAAAAR8M/HACNNC88564/s1600/Lo+Mai+Pau.jpg\"><img src=\"http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-_t2-e91Hjmc/T4ZVSD9tupI/AAAAAAAAR8M/HACNNC88564/s800/Lo+Mai+Pau.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"332\" height=\"500\" border=\"0\" /></a><br /> <span style=\"font-size: x-small;\"><em>鸡窝包</em><em> Ji Wo Pau (Chicken Nest Pau)$3</em></span><br /> <br /> <strong>Conclusion </strong><br /> <br /> With prices of Dim Sum in restaurants going through the roof, coffeeshop Dim Sum places like Lai Kee are offering us an attractive, affordable alternative.&nbsp; I do hope to blog more such stalls, so do write in if you know of any stalls that are serving up good, affordable Dim Sum! <br /> <br /> </p>\r\n<div class=\"separator\" style=\"clear: both; text-align: center;\"><a style=\"clear: left; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-right: 1em;\" href=\"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-HTyoS60oDAk/T4ZVUrXe3rI/AAAAAAAAR8g/4o-6bbVAS5I/s1600/Stall.jpg\"><img src=\"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-HTyoS60oDAk/T4ZVUrXe3rI/AAAAAAAAR8g/4o-6bbVAS5I/s200/Stall.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"200\" height=\"132\" border=\"0\" /></a></div>\r\n<p>Lai Kee Pau<br /> Blk 69 Bedok South Ave 3<br /> 6.30am and 9.30pm<br /> 90261698<br /> Branches:&nbsp; Clementi St 12, Blk 107 <br /> Bukit Batok St 21 Ave 6, Blk 207</p>",
            "blogid": "220",
            "comments": "51"
        }
    ],
    "lastid": "63"
},
"status": 1
```

}

Anyone please help me..

Comment: what do you mean "can't parse the json object"?

Comment: acces from a browser or some thing so can see how the tag is coming

Comment: If you want to parse json file, you can refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420003/android-internal-storage-how-to-properly-parse-a-json-text-file?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display HTML, you can use a WebView. If you need limited support for basic HTML tags, you can use Html.fromHtml